# Setting users location in a cookie - Efficient workflow?

Tags: cookies, nginx

User visits site

```
Has user got "location" cookie set?

    Yes - Print "country" value from cookie on page
           - Finish

    No  -  Do geoip look up with nginx

        Was this successful?

            Yes - Store value in cookie
                   - Print "country" value from cookie on page
                   - Finish

            No  - Do not print "country" on page
                   - Finish
```

Is this is the most efficient and proper workflow for this?

Comment: Yes, but don't rely on that cookie for anything critical. It can be spoofed (of course, geoip can also be foiled using proxies).

Comment: Thank you. If you add this as an answer ill make it as accepted.